# How can i change a h2 position inside a specific page using css?

Tags: jquery, html, css, containers

What happens is that

there are multiple pages and all of them have h elements nested inside a generic container div class.

so, to edit a specific h2 element inside a specific page in css, i can't simply edit the h2 or the container, neither other stuff that i've tried:

1. putting a exclusive div class for that h2 and then trying to style it the regular way
2. putting the h2 in an id, like this: " blablablah "

css:

.faq_title h2 {}

h2 faq_title {}

just faq_title {}

3. also tried to create 2 containers for that page just so i could style that h2:

""

then in css:

.container_help h2 {}

---

i would really apreciatte some help in this, if someone could just... if i learn this i'll probably not have to bother no one for a few hours

thanks!!!

Comment: Hey Mateus! I recommend you to read the guide [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Provide more information about your CSS / HTML so we can try to help!

Answer (score 2):

You must apply CSS styling to the h2 via selectors.

```css
.divname h2:nth-child(3) { /* Make the 3rd h2 blue */
  color: blue; 
}

.divname h2:nth-child(even) { /* Make the even h2's red */
  color: red;
}

.divname h2:nth-child(6) { /* Make the 6th h2 italicized */
  font-style: italic; 
}
```

```html
<div class="divname">
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
</div>
```

Source: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/ChrisPlz/pen/psfdD)

Answer (score 1):

from what i understand is that you want to edit it like change text color blablabla am i correct?

if so then you can use this:

```
.faq_title h2 {
 display:block;
 color: red;
 }
```

Comment: you got it right ben, but what i tried to put in the example is that i tried a syntax exactly like yours and it didn't work. i wanted to pad it and move it around so i tried line-height, margin, padding, etc. maybe that could be the issue, no ?

Comment: you could try to do 

position:absolute;
top: 300px;
left: 20px;

Comment: line height is not for moving it around